# Xcode 6 Git No Remotes Available

Tags: xcode, git, ssh

I have been connected to my remote repo for a while now through Xcode with no problems. All of a sudden today, Xcode (v6.1 which I've had since it came out) tells me to enter a password to connect to my remote repo. My repo is connected via ssh so should I even need a username and password? When I try to pull/push Xcode says "No Remotes Available", but I can successfully pull/push via command line. I have already seen

[Gitlab - Xcode Can't connect with remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20266294/gitlab-xcode-cant-connect-with-remote-repository)

[Xcode 4.4 - no remotes found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11724847/xcode-4-4-no-remotes-found)

But none of the answers there seem to help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea what happened, but I needed to go to Xcode > Preferences > Accounts and delete the repository it had listed there.

Comment: Sort of.  When I went into Xcode > Preferences > Accounts and selected the desired remote repository, I saw a red "!" next to an empty password field and a comment that "authentication failed".  Re-entering the password fixed the problem.

Answer (score 7):

I had this same issue.  It turns out that all I needed to do was go into "Configure [Project Name]", which is located here:

[image: Menu uou need]

Once I entered the URL here, then I was good to go.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Steps to resolve"No remotes available"]

i have resolve "No remotes available" using these steps...

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem a few times, where the problem was the address of the repository wasn't right.  In several cases the difference was simply a dash in the name, i.e.

> https://name@bitbucket.org/teamname/reponame.git
>   vs
>   https://name@bitbucket.org/teamname/repo-name.git

I don't know how the dash went missing, or if at some point the requirement for the dash appeared, but the result was "No remotes available".

To fix the problem I just needed to remove the remote in Xcode under Source Control/Working Copies/Configure and then re-add it with the proper address, as well as remove and re-add the repository under Preferences/Accounts.  Once the address was correct for both of these everything worked properly again.